# Ascending Hi Cut Filter?

Tags: audio-recording, microphone, signal-processing

I Tracked a guitar track and for a certain section there is a transition guitar part, and it would sound amazing with an ascending hi cut filter, but i have no idea how to implement that into the recording. Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 5):

I assume you're talking about what I would call a lowpass filter sweep: a lowpass (hi-cut) filter starts out cutting out most of the signal, and gradually raises the cutoff frequency until the whole signal is heard.

I assume you're using some kind of [DAW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation) software like Reaper or Pro Tools or something like that. Generally, what you'll do is insert a lowpass filter as an effect on your guitar track. Set the filter's cutoff frequency where you want it to start, and then use the DAW's automation feature (this is very common for DAWs to have) to make the cutoff rise over time.

I personally like how this effect sounds with a little bit of resonance: if your filter has a resonance (sometimes called "peak") dial, try turning it up a little bit. It emphasizes the current cutoff frequency, which makes the effect a little bit more obvious. Careful not to turn it up too high - some filters will self-oscillate at high resonances, which makes terrible and hugely loud sounds. Sometimes this is desirable. Often it is not.

Comment: yeah i am talking about a low pass filter, and im using logic express 9, i tried to do what you said, accept while we were recording the track and i raised it over the time i wanted it to, but there was no effect. shouldn't there be one?

Comment: Worth noting that what you've done there is nothing else but, you've implemented a Wah-Wah pedal in software.